# Pentaho report.setQuerty

Tags: pdf, report, hql, pentaho

I'm able to generate a true report by pre-configuring the (dbconntion + queries and passing parameters) within the prpt and calling it from java. It's working fine.

Problem: I am tring to use `report.setQuery("dummyQuery","SELECT NAME,ID FROM test.person");//some query` to dynamically generate report.  Is this possible?

When I use report.setQuery with same query, my report generates a blank pdf.
I think I should configure an HQL datasource to achieve this.

pre-config PRPT - I'm displaying 2 values, NAME and ID.

I'm able to generate this pdf dynamically through passing parameters.
Please guys help to generate this pdf dynamically thourgh setQuery or "how to use setQuery".
I really want to learn generating pentaho pdf reports.

```
    package com.report;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    import org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.ClassicEngineBoot;
    import org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.MasterReport;
    import org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.output.pageable.pdf.PdfReportUtil;
    import org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.Resource;
    import org.pentaho.reporting.libraries.resourceloader.ResourceManager;

    /**
     * Servlet implementation class Generate
     */
    @WebServlet("/Generate")
    public class Generate extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
         */
        public Generate() {
            super();
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
         *      response)
         */
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try{
            response.reset();
            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            ClassicEngineBoot.getInstance().start();
            ResourceManager manager = new ResourceManager();
            manager.registerDefaults();
            String PrptPath ="C:\\Users\\3692902\\Desktop\\pentahoTest.prpt";


            //generate report through pre-configured prpt (db connection + query)
            Resource res = manager.createDirectly(new File(PrptPath), MasterReport.class);
            MasterReport report = (MasterReport) res.getResource();
            report.getParameterValues().put("IDValue",101);

            //generate report through query?????
            //report.setQuery("SELECT ID FROM test.person");

            PdfReportUtil.createPDF(report,response.getOutputStream());
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
         *      response)
         */
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are loading the report from a PRPT file. So why dont you predefine your query in the Report-Designer by adding a SQL-Data-Source (Menu: Data->Add Data Source->SQL)?

Then, assuming you want to filter by IDValue, you would set your query (inside PRD, NOT your code) to:

```
SELECT ID FROM test.person WHERE ID = ${IDValue}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the "hardest" way to generate a report with reporting engine embedded in java.

Download Pentaho Report Designer matching the version of the engine you are using (eg: [Pentaho Report Designer 5.4](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pentaho/files/Report%20Designer/5.4/prd-ce-5.4.0.1-130.zip/download), [Pentaho Reporting Engine 5.4](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pentaho/files/Report%20Designer/5.4/pre-classic-sdk-5.4.0.1-130.zip/download)).

From Pentaho Report designer, create a new report, and start creating it ([1. Creating your first report](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/Reporting/01.+Creating+Your+First+Report))create your connections (or any datasource you need), create your queries, and define your parameters.

Finally, use your own code above to call the report from the servlet and display it.

Remember, Pentaho Report Designer is where you define ALL what you need in the report, then just send parameters and generate it from everywhere!.